# Uploading PDF to external API results in blank pages inside PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm new to Node.js and I need to upload some PDFs to an external API (Zip Forms).

Right now I have the code below but the PDF pages are blank when they arrive at the destination. I tried saving the PDF locally, using the same binary data that I'm sending to the API, and the PDFs are correctly saved.

I am also using `setTimeout` method here because I cannot find a method that waits for the PDF to read, before sending it to the API.

Also tried `binary` instead of `latin-1` in `readFileSync` method, but it doesn't change anything.

Code:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request');
const { createWriteStream, readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const s3 = new aws.S3(); // Pass in opts to S3 if necessary

// Look up order and related info.
var order = await Order.findOne({ id })
.populate('agent');

if (createZiplogixTransaction) {
  ziplogixTransactionId = await sails.helpers.ziplogix.createZiplogixTransaction.with({
    ziplogixContextId: ziplogixContextId,
    transactionName: order.propertyStreetAddress + ', ' + order.propertyCity,
    // FUTURE: if the transaction helper is updated, include actual order information
    // e.g. Primary seller name, property street address, etc.
  });
}

if (!order) {
  throw 'noSuchOrder';
}

// Permissions
if (this.req.me && this.req.me.accountType !== 'agent' && !ziplogixContextId) {
  throw 'forbidden';
}

let savedPdfs = await PdfOrderExternalId.find({ orderId: id });

await PdfOrderExternalId.destroy({
  where: { orderId: id }
});

for (const pdf of pdfs) {
  let url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: 'disclosure-pdfs',
    Key: pdf.uploadFd,
    Expires: 60 * 5
  });

  let file = createWriteStream(`/tmp/${pdf.slug}.pdf`);
  await https.get(url, async (response) => {
    await response.pipe(file);

    // Need to wait for file to write on disk :|. Doesn't work with await or Promise (Why? IDK)
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let postData = await readFileSync(`/tmp/${pdf.slug}.pdf`, 'latin1');

      let queryString = `Name=${pdf.displayName}&Description=${pdf.displayName}`;

      savedPdfs.forEach(item => {
        if (item.pdfTemplate === pdf.pdfTemplate) {
          queryString += `Id=${item.externalId}`;
        }
      });

      request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${sails.config.custom.ziplogixApiBaseUrl}/transactions/${ziplogixTransactionId}/documents/file?${queryString}`,
        headers: {
          'X-Auth-ContextID': ziplogixContextId,
          'X-Auth-SharedKey': sails.config.custom.ziplogixSharedKey,
          'Content-Type': ['application/pdf', 'application/pdf']
        },
        body: postData
      }, async (error, response, body) => {
        // code here ...
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
}

await exits.success(Date.now());
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you